# React hook - onFocus and onBlur

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have changed the code from components to hooks.
I'm completely new to it and i'm learning react
and i need help to change it to hooks
what should i do to make it work on functional react ?

- update:

- I have issued the solutions bellow but when i click on the input it takes me to the top of the page

```
  const [nameFocused, setNameFocused] = useState(true);
<FormGroup
                    className={classnames("mt-5", {
                      focused: nameFocused,
                    })}
                  >
                    <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="ni ni-user-run" />
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input
                        placeholder="Your name"
                        type="text"
                        onFocus={(e) => setNameFocused(true)}
                        onBlur={(e) => setNameFocused(false)}
                      />
                    </InputGroup>
                  </FormGroup>
```

Not relevant:

```
<FormGroup
                    className={classnames("mt-5", {
                      focused: state.nameFocused,
                    })}
                  >
                    <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="ni ni-user-run" />
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input
                            placeholder="Your name"
                            type="text"
                            onFocus={e => this.setState({ nameFocused: true })}
                            onBlur={e => this.setState({ nameFocused: false })}
                          />
                    </InputGroup>
                  </FormGroup>
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `useState` hook in your component.

Here `nameFocused` is a state and `setNameFocused` is equal to `this.setState({ nameFocused: ...})` in class component.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

...
   const [nameFocused, setNameFocused] = useState(false)
              
   return (
    <FormGroup
      className={classnames("mt-5", {
        focused: nameFocused,
      })}
    >
      <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
          <InputGroupText>
            <i className="ni ni-user-run" />
          </InputGroupText>
        </InputGroupAddon>
        <Input
              placeholder="Your name"
              type="text"
              onFocus={e => setNameFocused(true)}
              onBlur={e => setNameFocused(false)}
            />
      </InputGroup>
    </FormGroup>

   )
...
```

Comment: TNX guys for your help, this is what i did before but it's takes me all the time to the top of the page for some reason when i click on the input

Answer (score 1):

I'll just tell you how to handle state with hooks, read the docs and try and figure out the other hooks on your own.

This is how you handle state with hooks. First, "declare" the state variable:

```
const [nameFocused, setNameFocused] = useState(false)
```

You'll have to `import { useState } from react` first. The `const [..]` part is array destructuring. Look it up if you're not familiar. Basically, how this works is, the `useState` hook returns an array of two things, the first one is the default value to the state variable, and the second is a function to set the state variable. And the value you pass into the `useState` function is treated as the default value. In this case, it's `false`. So, after this line of code, we have the `nameFocused` variable with the value `false` and the `setNameFocused` function to set the value of the variable.

Like I already mentioned, the `setNameFocused` function can be used to the set the value of the state `nameFocused`. So your `onBlur` and `onFocus` handlers will look like:

```
...
  onBlur={() => setNameFocused(false)}
  onFocus={() => setNameFocused(true)}
...
```

One important thing to note is that the hooks should always to called in the same order, ie the hooks should never be called in an if block or anything similar.

Comment: Still it takes me to the top of the page

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky You're focusing the Form, not the input. So, when it's focused it will take you to the top of the page.

Comment: I have removed the:className={classnames("mt-5", {
                      focused: nameFocused,
                    })} 
and i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import React,{useState} from "react"
```

1 change the class definition to a function definition and delete every this keyword.(command+shift+L) on vscode

```
let first_function = ()=>{...}
```

2 change the render() to return

3 group all your state into a single initial state variable[optional]

```
let initialState = {nameFocused:true || false}
```

4 Inside your functional component declare your states

```
let [state,setState] = useState(initialState)
```

5 when setting state with the useState hook

```
setState((previousState)=> ({...previousState, newState}))
```

example:

```
<Input
    placeholder="Your name"
    type="text"
    onFocus={e => setState((prev)=>({...prev, nameFocused: true }))}
    onBlur={e => setState((prev)=>({...prev, nameFocused: false }))}
  />
```

6 we have the useReducer hook , and with this you are free from the trouble of always keeping count of the previous state.
[react doc react hooks(useReducer)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: it takes me to the top of the page for some reason

Comment: className={classnames("mt-5", {
                      focused: nameFocused,
                    })} , If this statement actually set true to the className name focused with a property to set focus on the entire form, then yes it would take you to the top of the page. Try to either comment out this logic or revisite your code

Comment: i have take it off and it still take me to the top of the page